# Narrowing types for multiprocessing manager proxies

Tags: python, generics, multiprocessing, typing

[`multiprocessing.managers.SyncManager.list`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/multiprocessing.html#multiprocessing.managers.SyncManager.list) returns a [`ListProxy[Any]`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/multiprocessing.html#proxy-objects), but I don't see a way to narrow `Any`?

As a workaround I can:

```
int_list = cast("ListProxy[int]", m.list())
```

And `int_list` is `ListProxy[int]`.

Note also that `"` are required on type to avoid:

```
TypeError: type 'ListProxy' is not subscriptable`:
```

---

Is there a better way?

Comment: much (all?) of the multiprocessing library has not been re-written to use type hinting. I would stick with your workaround.

Comment: You can narrow `Any` by assignment ([like this](https://mypy-play.net/?mypy=master&python=3.10&flags=strict&gist=0297788836516545f38c63f5935b958c)), `cast` with `Any` is necessary only if you're trying to use this in some nested expression context.

Answer (score 0):

A slightly nicer version using the [typeshed definitions](https://github.com/python/typeshed/blob/62292cdd93eacab55ccab23b0ddedad4f753a31b/stdlib/multiprocessing/managers.pyi):

```
results = m.list(cast(list[int], []))
```